# LateInitializationError: Field 'secondHalf' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

LateInitializationError: Field 'secondHalf' has not been initialized

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image. Check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "**initState**" method. Not "initStat" please check and try.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```